# Finding conditional expected value

Tags: self-study, random-variable, expected-value, joint-distribution, conditional-expectation

Given that X and Y are two independent exponentially distributed random variables with parameters a and b respectively.

let Z = max(X,Y)

find E[X|Z]

attempt:

I found that:

P(Z=X) = b/(a+b)
and
P(Z=Y) = a/(a+b)

however I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the question. E[X|Z] cannot have an X in it, thus the term bX+1 in the numerator has to be incorrect.

Comment: @Greenparker I edited the question to remove the "prove part". How would you do this in general?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: HINT: You know that both $X$ and $Y$ are less than $Z$. Its basically saying that $X\leq Z$. You've calculated $P(X=Z)$, so now can you do the rest?